# Designing REST API microservices for booking a flight ticket

Tags: microservices

I'm trying to identify overall components interaction and REST API interaction for a microservice that deals with flight booking.

A user select a flight seat and provides the details to a microservice API (Ex:

```
bookFlightTickets(FlightBookingRequest request) {
...}
```

Lets say, this service needs to hold the booking temporarily for X mins till the user completes payment system.

On a broader picture, required microservices would be:

1) FlightSystem microservice (Returns details of flights/seats)
2) Payment Microservice
3) Flight booking microservice

How would the bookFlightTickets API look like? Since it needs to hold the reservation temporarily, would it be an asynchronous microservice?

Any suggestions on the overall flow? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you to look at [.NET Microservices: Architecture for Containerized .NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/) Dispite it written by Microsoft it has a lot of general microservices design appoaches and bunch of useful links to other good books.

As of your explanation Flight booking microservice should receive bookings and hold them for some time so user will be able to make payment.

My thougths regarding microservices organozation.

1. The Flight booking microservice may have `POST` endpoint for reservation (like `/api/v1.0/reserve`)
2. I think it also should write reservations to DB so FlightSystem microservice returns reserved seats as occupaed to prevent double booking. It should set reservation date on reserved seats in DB so if seat is not paid in time it will be made vacant again. This can be achieved with [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice). I think it will be bad idea to put reserved seats in cache. In case of microservice restart reserved seats may be displayed as vacant and this may create inconsistent user experience
3. The payment microservice can make reservation permanent in case of sucessfull payment.

You may divide you DB in following parts (It's good idea for each microservice to have it own DB)

1. Seats DB which holds vacant/reserved seats. FlightSystem microservice can be responsible for it.
2. Temporary reserved seats DB with Flight booking microservice can be responsible for it
3. Payment service may hold payments DB

Services may [establish async link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/integration-event-based-microservice-communications) (like AMQP) to communicate to each other. FlightSystem will ask Flight booking microservice using AMQP for temporary reserved seats to correctly show occupaed seats. Payment service will tell to Flight booking microservice to permanently reserve seat in case of sucessful payment. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have been reading about event-driven microservices approach. I wasn't sure if it is highly prevalent everywhere or companies are just starting to use this approach. W.r.t setting a reservation date in DB for temporary holding, another alternative can be setting a TTL for the row so that it expires if the user doesn't book within the given time.